# ASP MVC 3 - Bind multi table linq query to gridview and export to .xls

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, linq, gridview, export

Below is a two-table linq query I'm using in an ASP MVC 3 controller to export to an `.xls` file. The table I'm querying, however, has a one-to-many relationship with a secondary table. When I step through the code, I can see that the linq query has executed as it should, with the correct amount of information in the `FixedStats` and `VariableStats` fields. However, when the file is exported to the spreasheet these two columns are nowhere to be found.

```
    public void ExportToCsv()
    {

        var grid = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView();

        //join a in db.BankListAgentId on b.ID equals a.BankID
        var banks = from b in db.BankListMaster

                          where b.Status.Equals("A")
                          select new
                          {
                              BankName = b.BankName,
                              EPURL = b.EPURL.Trim(),
                              AssociatedTPMBD = b.AssociatedTPMBD,
                              Tier = b.Tier,
                              FixedStats = from a in db.BankListAgentId
                                           where a.BankID == b.ID &&
                                                 a.FixedOrVariable.Equals("F")
                                               select new { a.AgentId },
                              VariableStats = from a in db.BankListAgentId
                                              where a.BankID == b.ID &&
                                                    a.FixedOrVariable.Equals("V")
                                              select new { a.AgentId }, 
                               Attachment = b.Attachment,
                              Status = b.Status
                          };

        grid.DataSource = banks.ToList();
        grid.DataBind();

        Response.ClearContent();
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=BankList.xls");
        Response.ContentType = "application/excel";
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
        grid.RenderControl(htw);
        Response.Write(sw.ToString());
        Response.End();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `String.Join` to combine list of `AgentId` values into one string, then supply it to the grid. Currently `FixedStats` and `VariableStats` are lists, that can't be presented as grid cell values:

```
  select new
  {
      FixedStats = String.Join("|", from a in db.BankListAgentId
                   where a.BankID == b.ID &&
                         a.FixedOrVariable.Equals("F")
                       select a.AgentId.ToString()),
  }
```

As Moby's Stunt Double noticed, creating dedicated view model would be recommended. Above solution may not work, because of ORM<->SQL translation issues.

Dedicated ViewModel example:

```
public class ExportVM
{
    public List<int> FixedStats { get; set; }
    public FixedStatsCombined 
    {
        get
        {
             return String.Join("|", FixedStats.Select(item => item.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You just beat me to it. Simplification of the relationships will be necessary. In addition I would recommend that OP creates a model to dump the rows into, that way you're not dealing with anonymous types - shady and dirty things they are :)

Comment: Unfortunately when I run the query with this syntax I get the following error: `LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String Join(System.String, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'1[System.String])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.`

Comment: @NealR: That is why you should created dedicated view model and that is what I meant when I wrote about ORM<->SQL translation issues.

Comment: Sorry, missed that part :)